# What is the optimal way to pivot a table?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table that looks something like this:

users_data_points:

```
id | users_id | data_types_id | value | events_id | time_inserted
```

data_type_id maps to some arbitrary thing like "name" or "address" or a thousand other data types.

So, for any individual user I can have N number of rows in this table.

There are millions of these rows.

Selecting from this table directly based on event_id is extremely fast and produces a long list of items where each user is represented by some number of rows, each containing a single data point.

However, when I need to pull a result that has each user and some subset of their data in INDIVIDUAL rows, I'm generally using subselects and now this process grinds down to a glacial pace.

My queries look (approx) like this:

```
select users_id as uid,
events_id as eid,
(select `value` from users_data_points where users_id = uid and events_id = eid and data_type_id = 3 limit 1) as 'firstName,
        -- ... however many more of these subselects I need here
        from users_data_points where events_id = 500 and date(time_inserted) between '2013-01-01' and date(now())
```

I'm entirely open to any alternative solution that can produce this result in a more efficient way.  In production I actually just grab the raw rows and then hash-map them together in Node. This is orders of magnitude faster than the subselects in SQL, but I'd much prefer to not split the work in this way if there's a better way to leverage mySQL to perform this task.

I'm totally open to temporary tables or views or derived tables or anything else that might work, but everything I've tried actually moves even slower than the above solution.

Comment: I definitely suggest finding an alternative to pivoting the table; it's not fun or efficient to do in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully approve G-Nugget's comment. Databases are not there to format data nicely, however, just for the sake of it, you can do

```
select users_id as uid,
events_id as eid,
max(case when data_type = 3 then `value` end) as first_name,
...
from users_data_points 
where events_id = 500 
and date(time_inserted) between '2013-01-01' and date(now())
group by users_id
```

If you choose min() or max() as aggregate function doesn't matter. With the `case...when`s (without the group by and aggregate functions) you get something like

```
user_id   |   first_name   |   last_name   |   ...
1             john             null            null
1             null             jack            null
1             null             null            whatever
```

With the group by and the aggregate function you get it in one line, and voila, you have your pivot without subqueries. This should run multiple times faster than what you have right now, still you might get even more performance pivoting your data on application layer.